# Interfaces Implementations used in Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, inheritance, interface, implementation

I have some problems with calling methods Action1 and Action2 of classes Class1 and Class2 from for-loop. I can't do `for (PreClass p : preClassArray)` because this methods are not implemented in PreClass. If I had only one interface, I could write `I1[] preClassArray = new I1[3];` and do `for (I1 p : preClassArray)` and call Action1, no problem. But I need Action2 also.

I thought about abstract methods Action1 and Action2 in PreClass, but I need this two methods only in Class1 and Class2, all other 98 classes that extends PreClass doesnt need it. So I don't want to implement 98 abstract Actions for them.

Please help me, to figure this out. I may be completely wrong, just started Java and programming. Thank you.

```
    //...
    PreClass[] preClassArray = new PreClass[3];
    pc[0] = new Class1();
    pc[1] = new Class2();
    pc[2] = new Class1();

    for ( /*Don't know how to point on I1 and I2 here*/ p : preClassArray) {
        p.Action1();
        p.Action2();
    }
}

class PreClass {
    //...
}

class Class1 extends PreClass implements I1, I2 {
    // realization of Action1 and Action2
}

class Class2 extends PreClass implements I1, I2 {
    // same here...
}

interface I1 {
    void Action1();
}

interface I2 {
    void Action2();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface inheritance:

```
public Interface I2 extends I1 { ... }

I2[] preClassArray = new I2[3];


for (I2 p : preClassArray) {
    p.Action1();
    p.Action2();
}
```

Comment: @alexbt why i inherit it

Comment: I guess that is what I needed. Thank you so much. I was wrong, thinking that implementing interface by another one needs rewriting of it:)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the specific instances you are working with are (my assumption here) then you will need to check and cast to be able to access its methods.

In other words, given an object you can check to see if that object implements a given interface or class. To answer your question I could have checked either but I feel that you should always go for the most specific check you could, in this case the interfaces you are interested in.

Also please note that convention dictates that method names should be camel case, as in the sample code provided.

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PreClass[] preClassArray = new PreClass[3];
        preClassArray[0] = new Class1();
        preClassArray[1] = new Class2();
        preClassArray[2] = new Class1();

        for ( Object p : preClassArray) {
                if ( p instanceof I1 ) ((I1)p).action1();
                if ( p instanceof I2 ) ((I2)p).action2();
        }
    }

    static class PreClass {
        //...
    }

    static class Class1 extends PreClass implements I1, I2 {
        public void action1() { System.out.println("Action1"); }
        public void action2() { System.out.println("Action2"); }
    }

    static class Class2 extends PreClass implements I1, I2 {
        public void action1() { System.out.println("Action1"); }
        public void action2() { System.out.println("Action2"); }
    }

    static interface I1 {
        void action1();
    }

    static interface I2 {
        void action2();
    }
}
```

This is performant and elegant, however, if you want to have some fun you could also use reflection! Here's some reflection fun (don't do this in production apps please!)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PreClass[] preClassArray = new PreClass[3];
    preClassArray[0] = new Class1();
    preClassArray[1] = new Class2();
    preClassArray[2] = new Class1();

    for ( Object p : preClassArray) {
        for ( Method m : p.getClass().getDeclaredMethods() ) {
            if ( m.getName().equals("action1") || m.getName().equals("action2") ) {
                try {
                    m.invoke( p );
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Certainly less elegant than the first example, but kind of cool to open your mind as to how easy you can hack away Java. I offer this second sample to raise awareness that your Java code is NEVER safe from someone trying to do something you never intended - this means that if you have a distributed library that holds secrets in memory, don't assume those secrets are safe.

Best!

Comment: Thanks! I hope I will understand reflection, when the time comes :) Instanceof is interesting, didn't know that. I'll try. Btw, thank you for pointing on camel case and convention in common. I'm reading it right know.